# Responder a pulsaciones de teclas igual que al hacer click sobre un botón

Tags: python, tkinter, eventos, teclado

Tengo una calculadora que funciona correctamente pero yo quiero que si se presiona la tecla <kbd>1</kbd> fuera como si se presionara el mismo botón en la interfaz grafica.

Mi idea era que constantemente este ejecutando el código de la calculadora y a su vez esperando constantemente que se presione una tecla, al presionarse esa tecla se llamaría a la misma función que cuando se presiona el botón en la interfaz grafica.

No se si hay una librería que me sirva para esto o si hay alguna otra forma de hacer lo que quiero me serviría.

Dejo el fragmento relevante de mi código:

```
tk.Label(borderwidth=10,relief="sunken",textvariable=textshow,width=16,height=1,bg="powderblue",font=("Arial",37),anchor="e").place(x=4,y=0)
tk.Button(frame,text="7",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("7"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=0,y=100)
tk.Button(frame,text="8",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("8"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=124,y=100)
tk.Button(frame,text="9",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("9"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=248,y=100)
tk.Button(frame,text="4",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("4"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=0,y=168)
tk.Button(frame,text="5",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("5"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=124,y=168)
tk.Button(frame,text="6",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("6"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=248,y=168)
tk.Button(frame,text="1",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("1"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=0,y=236)
tk.Button(frame,text="2",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("2"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=124,y=236)
tk.Button(frame,text="3",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("3"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=248,y=236)
tk.Button(frame,text="0",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("0"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=124,y=304)
tk.Button(frame,text=".",width=6,font=("Arial",25),borderwidth=0,command=lambda:write("."),activebackground="gray").place(x=0,y=304)
tk.Button(frame,text="/",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=Division,borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=372,y=100)
tk.Button(frame,text="×",width=6,font=("Arial",25),borderwidth=0,command=Multiplication,activebackground="gray").place(x=372,y=168)
tk.Button(frame,text="–",width=6,font=("Arial",25),borderwidth=0,command=Substract,activebackground="gray").place(x=372,y=236)
tk.Button(frame,text="+",width=6,font=("Arial",25),borderwidth=0,command=Sum,activebackground="gray").place(x=372,y=304)
tk.Button(frame,text="Clear",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=clear,borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=248,y=304)
tk.Button(frame,text="=",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=equal,borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=372,y=372)
tk.Button(frame,text="Delete",width=19,font=("Arial",25),command=delete,borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=0,y=372)
root.tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola Franco, la pregunta es muy amplia ¿Qué framework estás usando para la interfaz gráfica? Cualquiera que uses tiene mecanismos para manejar eventos de teclado de forma asíncrona para hacer lo que quieres.

Comment: Estoy usando Tkinter

Comment: Mírate [tkinter-events-and-bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm). Simplemente enlaza el evento que quieras con la callback que ya tienes asociada al botón de turno, p.e `tu_widget.bind("1", foo)`. Si quieres puedes editar la pregunta, añadiendo tu código o al menos un [mcve] para poder responder en base a algo concreto e intento responderla.

Comment: Gracias voy a buscar, ya la edito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La base de una interfaz gráfica en Tkinter y generalmente en cualquier otro framework gráfico es el llamado ciclo principal (mainloop). La principal función de este ciclo es estar constantemente a la espera de eventos y responder adecuadamente a ellos cuando se produzcan. Un evento puede ser hacer click en un botón, posicionar el cursor del ratón en un widget, pulsar una tecla del teclado, etc. Básicamente cualquier interacción que el usuario pueda hacer con la interfaz generará un evento que puede producir que algo se ejecute. Los eventos no solo proceden de la interacción del usuario,  pueden ser eventos generados por el administrador de ventanas del sistema, eventos lanzados por el propio código de la app, etc.

Cuando haces click en tus botones se genera un evento, ese evento es recogido por el mainloop y se encarga de responder al mismo de forma adecuada, en tu caso llamar a la función `lambda: write(...)`. Esto ocurre porque en el inicializador del widget `Button` se genera un enlace (binding) implícito entre el evento (click en el botón) y el objeto al que se debe llamar cuando el evento ocurra mediante el argumento `command`.

De la misma forma que enlazas ese evento con la función, puedes enlazar el evento de teclado con la misma función. La sintaxis general es:

```
widget.bind(evento, callback)
```

Existen tres métodos para enlazar eventos, a grandes rasgos:

- `bind`: solo enlaza el evento para ese widget en concreto.
- `bind_class`: enlaza el evento para todos los widgets de esa clase (Button, Frame, Label, etc) en la aplicación.
- `bind_all`: enlaza el evento para la aplicación en conjunto, sin importar el widget dónde el evento se produzca.

Los eventos se pasan a dichos métodos mediante una cadena con la forma general:

```
<modificador-tipo-detalle>
```

Por ejemplo, `"<Double-Button-1>"` es el evento generado cuando se pulsa el botón 1 (izquierdo del ratón) dos veces seguidas (doble click izquierdo).

Para el caso que nos ocupa, los eventos del teclado:

- `"<Key>"` enlaza cualquier tecla.
- Los caracteres caracteres imprimibles exceptuando el espacio y los propios paréntesis angulares `<>` se indica simplemente con el carácter. Por ejemplo `bind("q", foo)` enlaza la pulsación de <kbd>q</kbd> con `foo`.
- Los caracteres no imprimibles (y las excepciones mencionadas) se especifican de la forma general vista antes, algunos de ellos:

  > ```
  > "<Space>"
  > "<Return>"
  > "<Tab>"
  > "<Cancel>" 
  > "<BackSpace>"
  > "<Shift_L>"
  > "<Control_L>"
  > "<Alt_L>"
  > "<Escape>"
  > "<Prior>" (Page Up)
  > "<Next>" (Page Down)
  > "<Left>"
  > "<Up>"
  > "<Right>"
  > "<Down>"
  > "<Print>"
  > "<Insert>"
  > "<Delete>"
  > "<F1>", "<F2>", ...
  > ```

Al callable llamado cuando el evento se produce **se le pasa el propio evento como primer parámero de forma automática**:

```
<KeyPress event state=Mod2 keysym=Return keycode=36 char='\r' x=280 y=-27>
```

por lo que debemos hacer que nuestra función acepte este parámetro, lo use o no:

```
def callback(event):
    pass

lambda event: foo
```

Te dejo un ejemplo basado en tu código con los bindings correspondientes para cada botón. Para simplificar, las funciones se limitan a imprimir:

```
import tkinter as tk


def write(char):
    print(char)

def Division():
    print("Division")

def Multiplication():
    print("Multiplicacion")

def Substract():
    print("Resta")

def Sum():
    print("Suma")

def clear():
    print("Limpiar")

def equal():
    print("=")

def delete():
    print("Eliminar")

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('550x550') 
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

tk.Button(frame,text="7",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("7"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=0,y=100)
tk.Button(frame,text="8",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("8"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=124,y=100)
tk.Button(frame,text="9",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("9"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=248,y=100)
tk.Button(frame,text="4",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("4"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=0,y=168)
tk.Button(frame,text="5",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("5"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=124,y=168)
tk.Button(frame,text="6",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("6"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=248,y=168)
tk.Button(frame,text="1",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("1"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=0,y=236)
tk.Button(frame,text="2",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("2"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=124,y=236)
tk.Button(frame,text="3",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("3"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=248,y=236)
tk.Button(frame,text="0",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=lambda:write("0"),borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=124,y=304)
tk.Button(frame,text=".",width=6,font=("Arial",25),borderwidth=0,command=lambda:write("."),activebackground="gray").place(x=0,y=304)
tk.Button(frame,text="/",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=Division, borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=372,y=100)
tk.Button(frame,text="×",width=6,font=("Arial",25),borderwidth=0,command=Multiplication,activebackground="gray").place(x=372,y=168)
tk.Button(frame,text="–",width=6,font=("Arial",25),borderwidth=0,command=Substract,activebackground="gray").place(x=372,y=236)
tk.Button(frame,text="+",width=6,font=("Arial",25),borderwidth=0,command=Sum,activebackground="gray").place(x=372,y=304)
tk.Button(frame,text="Clear",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=clear,borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=248,y=304)
tk.Button(frame,text="=",width=6,font=("Arial",25),command=equal,borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=372,y=372)
tk.Button(frame,text="Delete",width=16,font=("Arial",25),command=delete,borderwidth=0,activebackground="gray").place(x=0,y=372)


# Numeros
for n in range(0, 10):
    root.bind(str(n), lambda event: write(event.char))
    root.bind(f"<KP_{n}>", lambda event: write(event.char))

# Punto decimal
root.bind(".", lambda event: write(event.char))
root.bind("<KP_Decimal>", lambda event: write(event.char))

# Operadores
root.bind("*", lambda _: Multiplication())
root.bind("<KP_Multiply>", lambda _:  Multiplication())
root.bind("/", lambda _: Division())
root.bind("<KP_Divide>", lambda _: Division())
root.bind("+", lambda _: Sum())
root.bind("<KP_Add>", lambda _: Sum())
root.bind("-", lambda _: Substract())
root.bind("<KP_Subtract>", lambda _: Substract())

# Clear (SUPR)
root.bind("<Delete>", lambda _: clear())

# Delete (BackSpace)
root.bind("<BackSpace>", lambda _: delete())

# = (Return/Intro)
root.bind("<Return>", lambda _: equal())
root.bind("<KP_Enter>", lambda _: equal())

root.mainloop()
```

Para que se acepten las entradas también desde el NumPad es necesario "duplicar" algunis bindings como podemos ver, (`"5"` y `"<KP_5>"` por ejemplo).