# Validación del Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, validación

Buenas noches, necesito si me podrian facilitar algún código que me permita controlar la validación de un `entry` usando `tkinter`.

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Me surgue la cuestión de utilizar en mi código, un `Entry` de `tkinter`; dicho `entry` necesito verificarlo cuando el foco no este activo y asi mostrar un mensaje al lado del `entry` que diga CORRECTO o INCORRECTO.

Agradezco soluciones, saludos!

Comment: @FJSevilla, en este caso, necesito validar un `entry` solo de números o solo de letras. Pero, me gustaria saber de forma general, para poder validar lo que necesite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Validación específica de los widgets Entry

---

La forma generalmente apropiada de validar un Entry es haciendo uso de dos argumentos de su constructor:

- **`validate`**: indica cuando debe ser validado el contenido del Entry, puede ser:

  - `None`: no se valida.
  - `"key"`: se valida cada vez que una tecla es pulsada (si tenemos el foco en el Entry)
  - `"focusin"`: se valida cuando el Entry obtiene el foco.
  - `"focusout"`: se valida cuando el Entry pierde el foco
  - `tk.ALL`: se valida en las tres situaciones anteriores
- **`validatecommand`**: recibe una referencia al callable a llamar cuando se lanza una validación. Debe retornar `True` o `False`. Generalmente lo que se hace es enlazar la callback interna de Tk a una función Python mediante el método `register`, esto permite pasar un número importante de argumentos muy útiles para validar el entry.

Un ejemplo en el que solo deja insertar enteros:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x100")

def on_validate(d, i, P, s, S, v, V, W):
    print(f"Nombre del widget: {W}")
    print(f"Acción: {d} (0=eliminar, 1=insertar, -1=otras)") 
    print(f"Indice del caracter a insertar/eliminar: {i}")
    print(f"Texto a insertar/eliminar: '{S}'")
    print(f"Texto del Entry antes de insertar: '{s}'")
    print(f"Texto del Entry si se valida: '{P}'")
    print(f"Tipo de la validación actual: {v}")
    print(f"Tipo de la validación que lanzó el evento: {V}")

    # Retornamos True si es válido o False en caso contrario
    if all(c in "0123456789" for c in P):
        return True
    return False

vcmd = (root.register(on_validate), '%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W')


entry = tk.Entry(root,validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)
entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

No tienes que pasar todos los argumentos (`d`, `i`, `P`, `s`, `S`, `v`, `V` y `W`), solo los que uses para validar. En este caso los paso todos para imprimirlos y mostrar que es cada uno a modo de ejemplo, en realidad solo uso `%P`.

Esto **impide (si `on_validate` retorna `False`) o permite (si retorna `True`) directamente que se ingresen caracteres no válido o que se elimine parte del contenido**.

Si solo quieres mostrar una alerta, pero no impedir que se ingrese texto no válido, puedes proceder igual que antes pero haciendo que en `on_validate` se lance la alerta (cambiar el texto del `Label` en tu caso), pero retornando siempre `True`:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x100")

def on_validate(P):
    if all(c in "0123456789" for c in P):
        label_var.set("CORRECTO")
    else:
        label_var.set("INCORRECTO")
    return True

vcmd = (root.register(on_validate), '%P')

entry1 = tk.Entry(root, validate="focusout", validatecommand=vcmd)
tk.Entry(root).pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
entry1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
label_var = tk.StringVar()
val_label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=label_var)
val_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

En este caso se valida al perder el foco (para ver la diferencia con `"key"`) y se ha añadido un `Entry` dummy al final para poder hacer que el entry a validar gane y pierda el foco haciendo click alternativamente en ambos.

### Validación mediante enlace de eventos general (`widget.bind()`)

---

Podemos usar el [enlace de eventos mediante `bind`/`bind_all`/`bind_class`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/271690/15089) como en cualquier otro widget.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x100")

def on_validate(event):
    if all(c in "0123456789" for c in event.widget.get()):
        label_var.set("CORRECTO")
    else:
        label_var.set("INCORRECTO")

entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry1.bind("<FocusOut>", on_validate)
tk.Entry(root).pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
entry1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
label_var = tk.StringVar()
val_label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=label_var)
val_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

### Validar mediante variable asociada

---

Esta sería otra posibilidad, aunque solo serviría para validar cada vez que se modifica el contenido, pero no ante otros eventos como cuando se gana o pierde el foco o se pulsa <kbd>Enter</kbd> por ejemplo. Básicamente monitorizamos la variable (por ejemplo `tkinter.StringVar`) asociada al `Entry` llamando a `on_validate` cada vez que la variable (y por tanto el Entry) a sido modificada:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x100")

def on_validate(*args):
    if all(c in "0123456789" for c in entry_var.get()):
        label_var.set("CORRECTO")
    else:
        label_var.set("INCORRECTO")

entry_var = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry_var)
entry_var.trace("w", on_validate)
entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

label_var = tk.StringVar()
val_label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=label_var)
val_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```