# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Entry'

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy tratando de trabajar con los datos que obtuve a partir de varios campos de texto de forma iterativa

Primero empezando con un dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
frame_data = {'valor': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'anio': [2017,2015,2017,2015,2016,2015,2017]}

df = pd.DataFrame(frame_data)
```

Y después lo que sigue del codigo

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
año = 2020

inv = tk.Tk()
inv.title("Mi ventana")
inv.minsize(500, 250)

interes = [] 
anios=[]
for i in range(2015, año + 1):
    a = i - 2015
    a = a + 3
    (tk.Label(inv, text="Selecione la tasa de inflación porcentual para el año ")
        .grid(row=a,column=1)
        )
    tk.Label(inv, text = i).grid(row=a, column=2)
    txt = tk.Entry(inv, width=7)
    txt.grid(column=3, row=a)
    interes.append(txt)
    anios.append(i)

def get_entries(df,anios,interes):
        df['mod']=df['valor']
        for u in range(len(anios)):
            for i in range(len(df)):
                if df['anio'][i]==anios[u]:
                    df['mod'][i]=df['valor'][i]+interes[u]
        print(df)

but = ttk.Button(inv,
                 text="Guardar tasas de interés ",
                 command=lambda: get_entries(df,anios,interes)
                 )
but.grid(column=4, row=a + 1)

inv.mainloop()
```

El problema es en la funcion get entries cuando solicito interes[u] pero no se como corregirlo

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `intereses` es una lista cuyos items son instancias de `tkinter.Entry` por lo que `intereses[u]` es un `Entry` y no puedes sumar un `Entry` a un entero como el error deja claro.

Necesitas obtener el valor del `Entry` con el método  `tkinter.Entry.get`, con lo que obtienes una cadena. Luego debes convertir dicha cadena a un `float` para poder operar con él:

```
df['mod'][i] = df['valor'][i] + float(interes[u].get())
```

Se asume que el usuario ingresa un valor correcto convertible a float, en caso contrario tendríamos un error. Sería apropiado validar el contenido de los Entries:

- [Validación del Entry](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/281143/15089)

Dicho esto,  en vez de usar dos ciclos `for` anidados, podrías usar un diccionario para almacenar cada año como clave y como valor el `Entry` correspondiente, lo que facilita y hace más eficiente la posterior operación:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk



año = 2020

inv = tk.Tk()
inv.title("Mi ventana")
inv.minsize(500, 250)

interes = {} 
for i in range(2015, año + 1):
    a = i - 2015 + 3
    (tk.Label(inv, text="Selecione la tasa de inflación porcentual para el año ")
        .grid(row=a,column=1)
        )
    tk.Label(inv, text = i).grid(row=a, column=2)
    txt = tk.Entry(inv, width=7)
    txt.grid(column=3, row=a)
    interes[i] = txt

def get_entries(df, interes):
    df['mod'] = df["anio"].map(lambda año: float(interes.get(año).get())) + df['valor']
    print(df)

but = ttk.Button(inv,
                 text="Guardar tasas de interés ",
                 command=lambda: get_entries(df, interes)
                 )
but.grid(column=4, row=a + 1)

inv.mainloop()
```