# Eventos de Teclado en Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola gente que tal no encuentro documentación que me ayude necesito saber como se aplican los **eventos** de **teclado** , por ejemplo al llenar datos de **entrys** me gustaría darle al **ENTER** para ingresar y no tener que hacer click con el mouse en el boton.

Dejo aqui dos botones hechos en tkinter python

```
# Boton Eliminar, Editar
       self.btn_eliminar = Button(frame2, text="ELIMINAR", cursor="hand2",bg="silver",font=("arial 10 bold"), command = self.eliminar_producto)
       self.btn_eliminar.grid(row=7, column=5, sticky=W+E)
       self.btn_eliminar.config(bd=5,relief="raised")

       self.btn_editar = Button(frame2, text="EDITAR", cursor="hand2",bg="silver",font=("arial 10 bold"), command= self.editar_producto)
       self.btn_editar.grid(row=7, column=6, sticky=W+E)
       self.btn_editar.config(bd=5,relief="raised")
       self.obtener_producto()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Los eventos de teclado por norma general se enlazan mediante los méodos bind, `bind_class` y `bind_all` como otros eventos. En la siguiente pregunta y mi respuesta a ella se explica por encima el funcionamiento de los eventos de teclado:

- [Responder a pulsaciones de teclas igual que al hacer click sobre un botón](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/271665/15089)

Tienes además una lista completa de los keysyms en:

- http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.htm

En el caso concreto que nos ocupa, los Entries, el enlace es lo mismo, simplemente enlaza el evento `<Return>` o `<Key-Return>` (es lo mismo)  a una calback, la cual será llamada cuando se pulse la tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd>. En dicha callback puedes validar el `Entry` (por ejemplo que no esté vacío, validación de email, etc) y a continuación pasar el foco a otro `Entry` (típico en formularios) o enviar el formulario si estamos en el último.

---

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent,  *args, **kwargs)

        self.columnconfigure(1,  weight=1)

        tk.Label(
            self, text="Usuario", anchor="w"
            ).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="WE")
        self.usuario_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.usuario_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="WE")

        tk.Label(
            self, text="Email", anchor="w"
            ).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="WE")
        self.email_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.email_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="WE")

        self.usuario_entry.bind("<Return>", self.on_enter_usuario_entry)
        self.email_entry.bind("<Return>", self.on_enter_email_entry)

        self.info_label = tk.Label(self, anchor="w", justify="left")
        self.info_label.grid(
            row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=(10, 0), sticky="WE"
            )

    def on_enter_usuario_entry(self, event):
        self.email_entry.focus_set()

    def on_enter_email_entry(self, event):
        usuario = self.usuario_entry.get()
        email = self.email_entry.get()

        error_texts = []

        # Validar campo no vacío
        if not usuario:
            error_texts.append("ERROR: El campo usuario es obligatorio")
            self.usuario_entry.config(bg="#ff8080")
        # Validación cutre de email
        if not "@" in email or not "." in email:
            error_texts.append("ERROR: El email no es válido")
            self.email_entry.config(bg="#ff8080")
        # Todo correcto, procesamos el formulario
        if not error_texts:
            self.usuario_entry.config(bg="#ffffff")
            self.email_entry.config(bg="#ffffff")
            self.info_label.config(
                text=f"Usuario: {usuario}\nEmail: {email}"
                )
        # Si no mostramos los errores
        else:
            self.info_label.config(text="\n".join(error_texts))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("400x200")
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=20, pady=25)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sos un genio muchas gracias por tu paciencia !! y buena onda ! siempre solucionandome la vida jaja ! gracias !